# Running a one-time command at login (Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to have a ssh tunnel open every time I log in to my Ubuntu machine. `.bashrc` seems like the wrong place for this since I only need one tunnel for the whole session, not a tunnel per `xterm`. `init.d` seems wrong since I would like this one for one user. `.bash_profile` is only for shell logins (I think) and I need this open for GUI use, too.
Where is the right place to put the `ssh` command that opens the tunnel, so that it will open in the background as soon as I log into the machine (GUI or shell), and stay open until I log out?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
~/.bash_login or ~/.bash_profile or ~/.profile
```

to run command on login and

```
~/.bash_logout
```

to run command or kill process on logout.